# Set icon for file type, Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, icons, mime-types, svg

I want the files with the extension **.api** to have some chosen **SVG** icon in the File Manager.

Assume, we have a file: /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps/utilities-terminal.svg

I add a new MIME type: create a **~/.mime.types** file with a line: **text/x-api api**

The question is: how should I link the SVG file name with the MIME type?

NOTE: No need of creating the custom icon, no need to launch some application by double-clicking. This question deals only with the linking of the given icon to file extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Dolphin, go to  **icon > properties > File Type Options > click icon > select icon > several times OK**. After close and open again the file manager, the icon should appears as selected (for all the same file types).

Comment: thanks for you answer! I installed Dolphin, but your the File Type Options opens no new window or any type of dialog. Maybe it's about my Cinnamon Mint...